# I don't understand how map() and prepper() work

Tags: r, tidymodels

The behavior of map is understood to the extent of the following code.

```
iris %>% 
  group_nest(Species) %>% 
  mutate(lm_mod = map(data,function(x){
    lm(Sepal.Width~Sepal.Length,x)
    }))
```

The above code works in my head as follows.

```
fot(i in unique(iris$species))
  data <- slice iris$species[i]
  function(data){lm(width ~ length,data)}
  lm_mod[i] <- function(data)
```

But I'm confused when I encounter new code.

```
folds %>%
  mutate(recipes = map(splits, prepper, recipe = recipe_code))
```

in my head

```
for(i in len(folds))
  folds$recipes <- prepper(splits) ??recipe = recipe_code??
```

Where does the recipe_code go in?

Comment: It translates roughly to `for(i in seq_along(folds$splits)) folds$recipes[[i]] <- prepper(folds$splits[[i]], recipe = recipe_code)`

Comment: The relevant part of the documentation is the description of the `...` argument in the help page `?map`: `...` Additional arguments passed on to the mapped function.